# Vaadin 7 flash wont work

Tags: flash, vaadin

I am using Vaadin 7 for my Webapplication and I am having a problem with the flash integration.

I tried to embed the Flash Animation like this:

```
@Theme("testtheme")
public class TsetUI extends UI {
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
    layout.setWidth("100%");
    setContent(layout);
    Flash flash = new Flash(null, new ThemeResource("flash/logo.swf"));
    layout.addComponent(flash);
}
}
```

but it does not display the animation, just some white space.

The swf file is located at:

WebContent/VAADIN/themes/testtheme/flash/logo.swf

I dont know what I am doin wrong. Please...i need some help on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found a solution to that problem:

i used the "old" way like in vaadin 6 to solve this issue (using an Embedded object):

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
    layout.setWidth("100%");
    setContent(layout);
    Embedded logo = new Embedded();
    logo.setSource(new ThemeResource("flash/logo.swf"));
    logo.setMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
    // TYPE_BROWSER
    logo.setType(2);
    layout.addComponent(logo);
}
```

One problem though: the performance is pretty bad, because the flash file is rendered pretty inconvenient (a lot of divs and iframe...)